# installing rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install rails on windows machine and getting  the following error.I spend 2 days to solve this,But I didn't get any success any help please.

```
While executing gem ...(Zlib::GzipFile::Error) not in gzip format.
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Are you using this to install it? http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167 (The Ruby Installer)

Comment: Yes I Installed ruby from here i.e rubyinstaller-1.9.2-p290!!!

Comment: Did you then installed `gem`? And then, did you then installed rails with `gem install rails`?

Comment: Which step is the one that you are failing on?

Comment: Did you try http://railsinstaller.org/ ?

Comment: @Bohdan:Yup but still I need to install more gems apart from rails,then I'm getting  same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Find out where your ruby is configured to look for sources:
C:>gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://gems.rubyforge.org/

If it is pointed at gems.rubyforge.org (which it is when first installed) then you’re pointed at the old web server so when ruby tries to get updates it gets an HTTP redirect (302) as a response instead of the expected data in GZIP format. It apparently doesn’t have an error handler configured to detect the redirect so it just gives up.

To fix it you have to update the list of sources. First add the correct source:
C:>gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
http://rubygems.org/ added to sources

Then remove the deprecated one:
C:>gem sources -r http://gems.rubyforge.org/
http://gems.rubyforge.org/ removed from sources

C:>gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/

Next update your ruby system:
C:>gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.3.7
:0:Warning: Gem::SourceIndex#search support for String patterns is deprecated
Updating RubyGems to 1.3.7
Installing RubyGems 1.3.7
RubyGems 1.3.7 installed

∩╗┐=== 1.3.7 / 2010-05-13

NOTE:

http://rubygems.org is now the default source for downloading gems.

You may have sources set via ~/.gemrc, so you should replace
http://gems.rubyforge.org with http://rubygems.org

http://gems.rubyforge.org will continue to work for the forseeable future.
...

Note that update verifies that the old source URL is no longer valid…

You should now be able to continue your installation, which in my case was rake.
C:>gem install rake
Successfully installed rake-0.8.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-0.8.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-0.8.7...

Comment: My current gem source is already been http://rubygems.org/
c:\gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES*****
http://rubygems.org/

Answer (score 0):

try fetching either URL (using wget or curl or telnet)

It seems that opendns breaks the internet on purpose.  I would avoid
 it at all cost.

Comment: I have no idea with wget and curl in windows.may be here some proxy issue?